# if empty list returns error, if not list Java 8 lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

Is there a more elegant way to do this:

```
List<Model1> list1 = this.dao.list();
list1.stream().findFirst().orElseThrow(Exception::new);
List<Model2> list2 = list1.stream().map(this::buildModel2).collect(toList());
```

Ideally, I would like to combine lines 2 and 3 into one line while retaining the same behaviour.

Comment: What's wrong with `if (list1.isEmpty()) { throw new IllegalStateException("list1 is empty"); }`?

Comment: please dont throw exception but a more specific exception if any

Comment: Nothing wrong with the if, just didn't want to use @Turing85 .

Comment: "Elegance" is using the straightforward if.

Comment: The exception was just an example, I use a specific exception @Zabuzard

Comment: I could use Assert from spring, but I wanted to see if there's another way

`List<Model1> list1 = this.dao.list();  
Assert.notEmpty(list1, "list empty");  
List<Model2> list2 = list1.stream().map(this::buildModel2).collect(Collectors.toList()); `

Comment: Please try to aim for readable and understandable code. Making code compact just for the sake of it does not really help anyone. Just saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run the  list through an `Optional` filtered on `!isEmpty()`:

```
List<Model2> list2 = Optional.of(list1).filter(c -> !c.isEmpty())
  .orElseThrow(Exception::new).stream().map(this::buildModel2).collect(toList());
```

——-

Actually, all 3 lines can become one line:

```
List<Model2> list2 = Optional.of(dao.list()).filter(c -> !c.isEmpty())
  .orElseThrow(Exception::new).stream().map(this::buildModel2).collect(toList());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, that is exactly what I was looking for.